# React-Boostrap center text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I just stumbled upon `React-Bootstrap`. I looked at their docs, but I couldn't find anything about centering text. Like this:

```
<h1 class="text-center">Hello World</h1>
```

So I was wondering if you can use the same technic, but apply it for React development instead. Like this for example:

```
<h1 classnName="text-center">Hello World</h1>
```

Cheers!

Comment: You have a typo. It's `className` not `classnName`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

React-Bootstrap **does not** inherit the Bootstrap styles. This means that you must import the css in order to use the classes that are in the standard Bootstrap library.

Read [**this**](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html) on the official documentation:

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included css. However, some stylesheet **is required** to use these components. How and which bootstrap styles you include is up to you, but the simplest way is to include the latest styles from the CDN.
>
> ```
> <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
>
> <!-- Optional theme -->
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
> ```
>
> For more advanced use cases you can also use a bundler like Webpack or Browserify to include the css files for you as part of your build process but that is beyond the scope of this guide. Also see http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ for details about customizing stylesheets to match your component use.

---

So once you've imported the styles, you should be able to do:

```
<h1 className="text-center">Hello World</h1>
```

Though, you'd have to spell `className` correctly too.

```js
const MyApp = () => <h1 className="text-center">Hello World!</h1>;

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

Alternatively, you can always define custom inline-styles if you'd prefer, like this:

```
<h1 style={{textAlign: "center"}}>Hello World</h1>
```

Comment: <h1 style={{textAlign: "center"}}>Hello World</h1>
This ended up being the simplest solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this bootstrap class will works

```
 <h1 className="m-auto"> text </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have type wrong spelling className.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is you'd like to align to center, Div, img, text, etc, you can align using;

```
<div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}> <button> Your text here </button> </div>
```